# exec function doesn't work

Tags: php, exec

I found this code from http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/convert_anything_to_tree_structures_in_php/, but I couldn't get it work. I am working on WIndow environment and the path I use is /sellable  where the sellable is the folder inside the working folder :

```
if(exec("find /etc/php5", $files)){
    // the $files array now holds the path as it's values,
    // but we also want the paths as keys:
    $key_files = array_combine(array_values($files), array_values($files));

    // show the array
    print_r($key_files);
}
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Iterator seems fine with me .. I manage to get the directory and subdirectory ... 
But my problem is that, I couldn't get the value of the Iterator object.. I can only print it out on screen..

If I use $file->getFilename() , it print on screen, however is I assign it to var, $file_name = $file->getFilename() , the var value is empty.. Why is that  ?

Comment: Sorry, I have to re-open this question .... 
I use the RecursiveIteratorIterator which works fine in my local machine Windows as well as Linux on 3rd party server..

Unfortunately, when I move to my client's server (OSCent) , the recursive doesn't works well ...My clients PHP is a Version 5.1.6 .. Could this be the root cause ?

Comment: In Windows env, I got these results :

Array
(
    [folder1] => folder1
    [folder1\folder1.1] => folder1\folder1.1
    [folder1\folder1.1\abc.txt] => folder1\folder1.1\abc.txt
    [folder1\folder1.1\notes.txt] => folder1\folder1.1\notes.txt
    [folder1\folder1.2] => folder1\folder1.2
    [folder1\folder1.2\abc.txt] => folder1\folder1.2\abc.txt
    [folder1\folder1.2\iphone icard.txt] => folder1\folder1.2\iphone icard.txt
    [folder1\folder1.2\Logo Saloon Rose House Site.pdf] => folder1\folder1.2\Logo Saloon Rose House Site.pdf

Comment: [folder2] => folder2
    [folder2\folder2.1] => folder2\folder2.1
    [folder2\folder2.1\notes.txt] => folder2\folder2.1\notes.txt
    [folder2\folder2.2] => folder2\folder2.2
    [folder2\folder2.2\iphone icard.txt] => folder2\folder2.2\iphone icard.txt
    [folder2\folder2.2\php_readfile.txt] => folder2\folder2.2\php_readfile.txt
    [folder3] => folder3
    [folder3\folder3.1] => folder3\folder3.1
    [folder3\folder3.1\3.odt] => folder3\folder3.1\3.odt
    [folder3\folder3.1\iphone icard.txt] => folder3\folder3.1\iphone icard.txt

Comment: [folder3\folder3.1\notes.txt] => folder3\folder3.1\notes.txt
    [folder3\folder3.2] => folder3\folder3.2
    [folder3\folder3.2\iphone icard.txt] => folder3\folder3.2\iphone icard.txt
    [New Folder] => New Folder
    [New Folder\folder4] => New Folder\folder4
    [New Folder\folder4\notes.txt] => New Folder\folder4\notes.txt
    [New Folder\folder4\PhotoPlus Reg.txt] => New Folder\folder4\PhotoPlus Reg.txt

Comment: [New Folder\folder4.1] => New Folder\folder4.1
    [New Folder\folder4.1\folder4.1] => New Folder\folder4.1\folder4.1
    [New Folder\folder4.1\folder4.1\notes.txt] => New Folder\folder4.1\folder4.1\notes.txt
    [New Folder\folder4.1\folder4.2] => New Folder\folder4.1\folder4.2
    [New Folder\folder4.1\folder4.2\folder4.2.1] => New Folder\folder4.1\folder4.2\folder4.2.1

Comment: [New Folder\folder4.1\folder4.2\folder4.2.1\folder4.2.1.1] => New Folder\folder4.1\folder4.2\folder4.2.1\folder4.2.1.1
    [New Folder\folder4.1\folder4.2\folder4.2.1\folder4.2.1.1\css.txt] => New Folder\folder4.1\folder4.2\folder4.2.1\folder4.2.1.1\css.txt
    [New Folder\folder4.1\folder4.2\iphone icard.txt] => New Folder\folder4.1\folder4.2\iphone icard.txt

Comment: [New Folder\notes.txt] => New Folder\notes.txt
    [New Folder\PhotoPlus Reg.txt] => New Folder\PhotoPlus Reg.txt
    [New Folder\php_readfile.txt] => New Folder\php_readfile.txt
    [New Folder\ts123456_10__1264538863.doc] => New Folder\ts123456_10__1264538863.doc
)

Comment: But in client's server I got these results :

Array
(
    [folder1] => folder1
    [folder1/folder1.1] => folder1/folder1.1
    [folder1/folder1.1/abc.txt] => folder1/folder1.1/abc.txt
    [folder1/folder1.1/notes.txt] => folder1/folder1.1/notes.txt
    [folder1/folder1.2] => folder1/folder1.2
    [folder1/folder1.2/abc.txt] => folder1/folder1.2/abc.txt
    [folder1/folder1.2/Logo Saloon Rose House Site.pdf] => folder1/folder1.2/Logo Saloon Rose House Site.pdf

Comment: [folder1/folder1.2/iphone icard.txt] => folder1/folder1.2/iphone icard.txt
    [folder3] => folder3
    [folder3/folder3.1] => folder3/folder3.1
    [folder3/folder3.1/iphone icard.txt] => folder3/folder3.1/iphone icard.txt
    [folder3/folder3.1/3.odt] => folder3/folder3.1/3.odt
    [folder3/folder3.1/notes.txt] => folder3/folder3.1/notes.txt
    [folder3/folder3.2] => folder3/folder3.2
    [folder3/folder3.2/iphone icard.txt] => folder3/folder3.2/iphone icard.txt
    [folder2] => folder2
    [folder2/folder2.1] => folder2/folder2.1

Comment: [folder2/folder2.1/notes.txt] => folder2/folder2.1/notes.txt
    [folder2/php_readfile.txt] => folder2/php_readfile.txt
    [folder2/folder2.2] => folder2/folder2.2
    [folder2/folder2.2/iphone icard.txt] => folder2/folder2.2/iphone icard.txt
    [New Folder] => New Folder
    [New Folder/folder4] => New Folder/folder4
    [New Folder/folder4/PhotoPlus Reg.txt] => New Folder/folder4/PhotoPlus Reg.txt
    [New Folder/folder4/notes.txt] => New Folder/folder4/notes.txt

Comment: [New Folder/PhotoPlus Reg.txt] => New Folder/PhotoPlus Reg.txt
    [New Folder/notes.txt] => New Folder/notes.txt
    [New Folder/ts123456_10__1264538863.doc] => New Folder/ts123456_10__1264538863.doc
    [New Folder/php_readfile.txt] => New Folder/php_readfile.txt
    [New Folder/folder4.1] => New Folder/folder4.1
    [New Folder/folder4.1/folder4.2] => New Folder/folder4.1/folder4.2
    [New Folder/folder4.1/folder4.2/iphone icard.txt] => New Folder/folder4.1/folder4.2/iphone icard.txt

Comment: [New Folder/folder4.1/folder4.2/folder4.2.1] => New Folder/folder4.1/folder4.2/folder4.2.1
    [New Folder/folder4.1/folder4.2/folder4.2.1/folder4.2.1.1] => New Folder/folder4.1/folder4.2/folder4.2.1/folder4.2.1.1
    [New Folder/folder4.1/folder4.2/folder4.2.1/folder4.2.1.1/css.txt] => New Folder/folder4.1/folder4.2/folder4.2.1/folder4.2.1.1/css.txt
    [New Folder/folder4.1/folder4.1] => New Folder/folder4.1/folder4.1
    [New Folder/folder4.1/folder4.1/notes.txt] => New Folder/folder4.1/folder4.1/notes.txt
)

Comment: The sequence of the result array is very important to me as I have to convert it into treeview ... The last node is crucial to populate a treeview..

Comment: My local machine is using PHP/5.2.9-2 while the other server that works well is using PHP Version 5.3.1 ...

So I am suspecting the client's server that using PHP Version 5.1.6 could be the caused of the non-sequencial result using RecursiveIteratorIterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` is a Linux command (an external Linux program).

Which means it will not be present on windows...

And `/etc/php5` really looks like an UNIX path to a directory ; and doesn't look like a path to a Windows directory.

So, two problems here :

- You have to find an equivalent of... `find`.

  - Maybe using something like cygwin ?
- You have to adapt the path, so it fits your system

But I'd say that **a PHP-only solution would probably be better** : there are functions and classes that will allow you to search files and iterate over the filesystem -- and it would work on both Linux and Windows, not depending on any external program.

For instance, to iterate over a directory, you might want to take a look to the [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) class -- and maybe also [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php).

Comment: Hi Martin, I got this from php error log.. 
[25-Feb-2010 20:23:14] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'DirectoryIterator::__construct(\sellable) [<a href='directoryiterator.--construct'>directoryiterator.--construct</a>]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory' in C:\wamp\www\waterwell\display_e_book.php:21
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\waterwell\display_e_book.php(21): DirectoryIterator->__construct('\sellable')
#1 C:\wamp\www\waterwell\e_book.php(40): include('C:\wamp\www\wat...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in C:\wamp\www\waterwell\display_e_book.php on line 21

Comment: DO I have to do anything to use the DirectoryIterator ?

Comment: BTW, I use this code :
$dir = new DirectoryIterator("/sellable");
foreach ($dir as $file) {
   if ($file->isDot()) {
       continue;
   }
   echo $file->getFilename() . "\n";
}

Comment: @redcoder : like the error message says : *"No such file or directory"* ;;; which means you are probably not specifying the right path as a parameter when instanciating `DirectoryIterator` ; I suppose `/sellable` is not a valid directory ; maybe you have to specify something like `C:/Users/.../sellable` ; or use a relative path, like '../sellable' ?

Comment: Yes, your are right martin. I use a wrong directory.. Should be resellable instead of sellable .. That codes is working now .. Thanks ..

Answer (score 2):

You are hardly going to get the `find` command, nor a `/etc/php5`  directory on a windows machine. Use PHP's built-in [**glob**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) or the <strike>DirectoryIterator</strike> [**RecursiveDirectoryIterator**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) (Thanks Pascal :)  instead. Glob can't iterate through sub-folders natively, but there are simple `globr` implementations in the User Contributed Notes on the linked page. The iterator can do this natively.

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tried it, but "dir /s /b c:\somedir" might work as a quick replacement for "find" on windows. a better (and more portable) solution would be to use the RecursiveDirectoryIterator or php's opendir/readdir functions to recursively list all files in a directory.

see example code here for example:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php